# Prove that there exists a non-zero vector $u$ such that $F(u)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, solution-verification

suppose we have a linear transformations $F: U \rightarrow V$ such that $\dim V <\dim U< \infty$. I want to show that there exists a non-zero element $u \in U$ such that $F(u)=0$. But I'm not sure if I'm in the right way to do this.

Here's what came to my mind: Let $B_V=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ be a basis for $V$ and $B_U=\{u_1,u_2,...,u_m\} $ a basis for $U$, such that $n<m$. Because the transformation:
$$B_V=\{F(u_1),F(u_2),...,F(u_n),F(u_{n+1}),...,F(u_m)\}$$

But the dimension of $V$ is $n$, then i must have $\{F(u_{n+1}),...,F(u_m)\}=\{0\}$ for arbitrary $u_{n+1},...,u_m$. Did i do something wrong? any tips? anything would be a great help! thanks in advance.

Comment: Try looking up about the Rank-Nullity Theorem. It's an important idea in Linear Algebra that will help you do this problem.

Comment: Your solution is wrong since one cannot guarantee that $B_V=\{F(u_1),F(u_2),...,F(u_n),F(u_{n+1}),...,F(u_m)\}$.

Comment: Your presuming you can do the sorting in your reasoning; this is "begging" the question.  You have to step back and either use the Rank-Nullity Theorem.  Or if your simple, like me: write out the terms and show that; given the independence of the basis vectors, You can _construct_ an element of U that contradicts the independence of the basis elements of the m basis vectors in U.    In other words, some vector of  U would be  driven to zero because of limited dependence in V.  In other words "pulling back" the limited basis elements of V leaves holes in U and must be in the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to expand Vishnu's comment, you need to use the Rank-Nullity Theorem (proof can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem#First_proof)), which states that for all $F:U\to V$,
$$\dim(U)=\dim(\operatorname{Im}F)+\dim(\operatorname{Ker}F)$$
Suppose there isn't a nonzero element $u \in U$  such that $F(u)=0$. That means $\operatorname{Ker}(T)=\{0\}$.

now using that fact, we can deduce that:
$$\dim(U)=\dim(\operatorname{Im}F)+0=\dim(\operatorname{Im}F)$$
but we know that $\operatorname{Im}F \subseteq V$ and so $\dim(U)=\dim(\operatorname{Im}F)\leq \dim(V)$,
in contradiction to our assumption that $\dim(V) < \dim(U)$.